# How can I make __init__ take a new value or an existing instance?

Tags: python

I have a pattern that looks similar to the following:

```
class Foobar(object):  # instances of this class will be referenced by others
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, value, foobar)
        self.value = value
        if isinstance(foobar, Foobar):
            self.foobar = foobar
        else:
            self.foobar = Foobar(foobar)

class Bar(object):
    def __init__(self, value, foobar)
        self.value = value
        if isinstance(foobar, Foobar):
            self.foobar = foobar
        else:
            self.foobar = Foobar(foobar)
```

This allows `Foo` and `Bar` to take either a new value (to create a `Foobar`) or an existing instance of `Foobar` as their `foobar` argument.

---

I would like to get rid of this redundant code:

```
# ...
        if isinstance(foobar, Foobar):
            self.foobar = foobar
        else:
            self.foobar = Foobar(foobar)
```

I considered the following, but it doesn't work due to infinite recursion in `Foobar.__new__()`:

```
class Foobar(object):
    def __new__(cls, value):
        if isinstance(value, cls):
           return value
        else:
           return Foobar(value)
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, value, foobar)
        self.value = value
        self.foobar = Foobar(foobar)

class Bar(object):
    def __init__(self, value, foobar)
        self.value = value
        self.foobar = Foobar(foobar)
```

---

What is the best way to allow classes to create new instances **or** use existing instances depending on the values passed to `__init__`?

Comment: Seems like a strange way of doing things. What's the use-case?

Comment: I am wrapping VCS "objects". `Foobar` may represent a repository and `Foo` my represent a user. I want an instance of a user to know about its repository. I would like to be able to do `User('Jace', repo='test')` or `User('Jace', repo=existing_instance_of_test)`.

Comment: If the issue with your first example is duplication of code, can you not use inheritance to factor out the duplicated block?

Comment: @Aya, I am now considering that option...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option would be to factor out the duplicated code with a mixin class...

```
class Foobar(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

class FoobarMixin(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        foobar = kwargs['foobar']
        if isinstance(foobar, Foobar):
            self.foobar = foobar
        else:
            self.foobar = Foobar(foobar)

class Foo(FoobarMixin):
    def __init__(self, value, **kwargs):
        super(Foo, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.value = value
        print self.value, self.foobar

class Bar(FoobarMixin):
    def __init__(self, value, **kwargs):
        super(Bar, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.value = value
        print self.value, self.foobar

foo = Foo('foo', foobar='foobar')
bar = Bar('bar', foobar=Foobar('foobar'))
```

...which prints...

```
foo <__main__.Foobar object at 0x7fa0fedf6050>
bar <__main__.Foobar object at 0x7fa0fedeaf10>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can get rid of the recursion by calling the base class `__new__()`:

```
class Foobar(object):
    def __new__(cls, value):
        if isinstance(value, cls):
           return value
        else:
           return object.__new__(cls, value)
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
```

Note that the first parameter to `__new__()` is a class, not `self`.

That said, I'm not convinced that this is a useful pattern.  In general, I'd recommend to accept instances in the constructor and leave the object construction to the calling code.  While magic that does the Right Thing often seems convenient, it usually causes more problems down the road than it is worth.

Comment: `self` in place of `cls` was a typo. I've edited my question to reflect this.

Comment: @JaceBrowning: Well, that was more of a side note anyway.  The main change is to call `object.__new__()` to avoid the recursion.

Comment: Your change indeed fixes my recursion problem. I ended up going with [Aya's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17349399/429533) as it is a better design pattern and less "magical".